# Domain of a function that accepts two vectors of $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: functions, vectors

Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(\vec{u}, \vec{v})=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$, where $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb R^n$. What is the domain of $f$? $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{2n}$?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes. These are w

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: BTW interesting convention or notation that $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\left(\vec{u},\vec{v}\right)\in\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @BrianTung I just wanted to clear my minor doubt I have in mind.

Comment: When a function accepts two vectors like this, it's sometime better to leave $\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n$ unsimplified, like that. Usually, it would be expected that a function with domain $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ accepts a single vector, which this doesn't. There is a rabbit hole we could go down about whether $\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n = \Bbb{R}^{2n}$ (technically not, but usually for completely useless reasons that we tend to ignore), but let's not go down that road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ for sure. Given **any** two vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we define $f(\vec{u},\vec{v}) := \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$.

Now, regarding the equality $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Conceptually, the sets $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are very different. Let us look at a concrete example. Take $n = 3$. An element $x$ of $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ is an **ordered pair** $(a,b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Since $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we can also say that $a$ and $b$ are triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, respectively, where $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, for each $i = 1, 2, 3$. Hence, $x = ((a_1,a_2,a_3),(b_1,b_2,b_3))$.

What about the elements of $\mathbb{R}^6$ (which is the set $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in the case $n = 3$)? Well, an element $y$ of $\mathbb{R}^6$ is a $6$-tuple, i.e., it is an **ordered sequence** $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5,c_6)$ of six real numbers.

Thus,
$$x = ((a_1,a_2,a_3),(b_1,b_2,b_3)) \quad \text{and} \quad y = (c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5,c_6).$$

The object $x$ is an ordered pair (or a $2$-tuple), and $y$ is a $6$-tuple. What would mean to say that $x = y$? We know that $(p,q) = (r,s)$ means that $p = r$ and $q = s$. But $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ are two ordered pairs. It would be tempting (and quite natural) to extend the notion of equality in this case, by stating that $x = y$ means that $a_1 = c_1$, $a_2 = c_2$, $a_3 = c_3$, $b_1 = c_4$, $b_2 = c_5$, and $b_3 = c_3$. And then we define this sort of equalities to get $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m = \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$.

This is all right. But maybe not the best approach (too many definitions).

Instead, we usually forget about all this details because we can identify each element of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ with one and only one element of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (and vice-versa). Formally, we are saying that we can construct a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. And this is quite natural, just take
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\varphi \colon & \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n & \to & \mathbb{R}^{2n} \\
& ((x_1,\dots,x_n),(y_1,\dots,y_n)) & \mapsto & (x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n).
\end{array}
$$
This means that everything that you do in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ can be reproduce in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (and vice-versa). Or in other words, it doesn’t matter if you work with an ordered pair $((x_1,\dots,x_n),(y_1,\dots,y_n))$ or with a single $2n$-tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n)$, you will always get the same results

Comment: Interesting. It seems like the Cartesian product of multiple sets can be interpreted differently when parenthesis are involved. Any element of $\mathbb R^{2n}=\underline{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\cdots\times\mathbb R}_\text{$2n$ times}$ is a tuple of $2n$ elements while $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n=(\underline{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\cdots\times\mathbb R}_\text{$n$ times})\times(\underline{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\cdots\times\mathbb R}_\text{$n$ times})$ is a tuple of two elements, each is $n$ tuple.

Comment: You’re right! It will depend on the parentheses. For example, $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is not the same as $\mathbb{R}^3$. The elements of $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ are of the form $((a,b),c)$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and the elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are of the form $(a,b,c)$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But (for simplicity) we ignore this technicality and consider these two sets to be the same.

Comment: Note that the identification of $((a,b),c)$ as $(a,b,c)$ is harmless. Both expressions “carry” the same information (the important stuff is the real numbers that appear in them)